# como logro llegar a este out?

Tags: r

```
> library(digest)  
> out <- digest(paste(x, y, sep=" "), algo = "md5", serialize = F)
```

donde:

x: es la cadena de texto: "ƒsta ser‡ una historia de terror. Ser‡ una historia polic’aca, un relato de serie negra y de terror. Pero no lo parecer‡. No lo parecer‡ porque soy yo la que lo cuenta. Soy yo la que habla y por eso no lo parecer‡. Pero en el fondo es la historia de un crimen atroz. Yo soy la amiga de todos los mexicanos. Podr’a decir: soy la madre de la poes’a mexicana, pero mejor no lo digo. Yo conozco a todos los poetas y todos los poetas me conocen a m’. As’ que podr’a decirlo. Podr’a decir: soy la madre y corre un cŽfiro de la chingada desde hace siglos, pero mejor no lo digo. Podr’a decir, por ejemplo: yo conoc’ a Arturito Belano cuando Žl ten’a diecisiete a–os y era un ni–o t’mido que escrib’a obras de teatro y poes’a y no sab’a beber, pero ser’a de algœn modo una redundancia y a m’ me ense–aron (con un l‡tigo me ense–aron, con una vara de fierro) que las redundancias sobran y que s—lo debe bastar con el argumento. Lo que s’ puedo decir es mi nombre. Me llamo"

y: es una cadena de texto desconocida de 7 letras may´usculas de la forma: A_____O

Si se cumple que:

```
> out
[1] "5580a2572d6e358ce8a493fd8739ff58"
```

Comment: ¿Qué tiene que ver la etiqueta letscencript? Y ya puestos... ¿qué estás preguntando exactamente? ¿En qué lenguaje se supone que está? (y además, parece haber un problema con el encoding de los caracteres no-ascii)

Comment: Bienvenida, te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y veas [ask], las tareas académicas no son bien recibidas si no se demuestra un esfuerzo en la mismas, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta para: a) mostrar lo que has intentado hasta ahora y que dificultades has tenido. b) Pega correctamente el texto (2066 o los detectives salvajes?) sino seguramente va a ser imposible generar el hash que estás mostrando. Saludos.

Answer (score 3):

ya sé que este tipo de preguntas no deben responderse, y que me arriesgo a un voto negativo por hacerlo, pero no he podido evitarlo. Me encantan los retos y esta pregunta tenía muchos.

1. ¿Qué se pregunta? Tras reformatear la pregunta para hacerla legible, e imaginar lo que hacen ciertas primitivas de un lenguaje no especificado parece que lo que pide es:

   > Cuál es el valor de Y tal que `X + " " + Y` sea una cadena cuyo hash md5 es "5580a2572d6e358ce8a493fd8739ff58", siendo `X` un fragmento de texto dado?

   Con el dato adicional de que Y se compone de 7 letras mayúsculas siendo la primera `A` y la última `O`.
2. ¿Cómo abordar el problema? Ya que un hash criptográfico es irreversible (no es posible, partiendo del hash, reconstruir la cadena que lo originó), el único enfoque es la fuerza bruta. Es decir, probar todas las combinaciones posibles de 5 letras mayúsculas para generar todos los valores de `Y` posibles y hacer para cada uno de ellos la operación `md5(X + " " + Y)` hasta encontrar una que produzca el hash deseado. Sólo son 26<sup>5</sup> combinaciones (11881376), no debería llevar más de un minuto.
3. ¿En qué lenguaje hacerlo? No se especifica, de modo que usaré el que más me gusta, python. [**Edit** Posteriormente la etiqueta de la pregunta fue editada. Parece que el lenguaje original era R.]
4. ¿Qué encoding usar para la cadena cuyo hash queremos calcular? Ya que los hashes operan sobre secuencias de bytes, y no de caracteres, es necesario convertir a bytes el texto. El enunciado no especifica qué encoding utilizar, de modo que tendría que probar con varios.
5. ¿Qué son todos esos caracteres raros en el texto que ha pegado el usuario? Véase cómo comienza: `ƒsta ser‡ una historia de terror.` Parece evidente que debería ser `Ésta será una historia de terror` y que por tanto el usuario ha recibido el texto con un encoding y lo ha visualizado con otro. ¡Más piezas para el rompecabezas! ¿cuál será el encoding original del texto?

## Resolviendo el rompecabezas

### Encodings

Para averiguar qué encoding tenía el texto original, he probado a codificar el símbolo `"‡"` en todos los encodings posibles soportados por python, para obtener un byte (o secuencia de bytes), que seguidamente pasé a codificar de nuevo con cada uno de los encodings posibles, para ver en cuál de ellos el resultado era una `"á"` (ignorando todos aquellos que producían error de codificación, claro):

```
codecs = ['ascii', 'big5', 'big5hkscs', 'cp037', 'cp273', 'cp424', 'cp437', 'cp500', 'cp720', 'cp737', 'cp775', 'cp850', 'cp852', 'cp855', 'cp856', 'cp857', 'cp858', 'cp860', 'cp861', 'cp862', 'cp863', 'cp864', 'cp865', 'cp866', 'cp869', 'cp874', 'cp875', 'cp932', 'cp949', 'cp950', 'cp1006', 'cp1026', 'cp1125', 'cp1140', 'cp1250', 'cp1251', 'cp1252', 'cp1253', 'cp1254', 'cp1255', 'cp1256', 'cp1257', 'cp1258', 'euc_jp', 'euc_jis_2004', 'euc_jisx0213', 'euc_kr', 'gb2312', 'gbk', 'gb18030', 'hz', 'iso2022_jp', 'iso2022_jp_1', 'iso2022_jp_2', 'iso2022_jp_2004', 'iso2022_jp_3', 'iso2022_jp_ext', 'iso2022_kr', 'latin_1', 'iso8859_2', 'iso8859_3', 'iso8859_4', 'iso8859_5', 'iso8859_6', 'iso8859_7', 'iso8859_8', 'iso8859_9', 'iso8859_10', 'iso8859_11', 'iso8859_13', 'iso8859_14', 'iso8859_15', 'iso8859_16', 'johab', 'koi8_r', 'koi8_t', 'koi8_u', 'kz1048', 'mac_cyrillic', 'mac_greek', 'mac_iceland', 'mac_latin2', 'mac_roman', 'mac_turkish', 'ptcp154', 'shift_jis', 'shift_jis_2004', 'shift_jisx0213', 'utf_32', 'utf_32_be', 'utf_32_le', 'utf_16', 'utf_16_be', 'utf_16_le', 'utf_7', 'utf_8', 'utf_8_sig']

for e in codecs:
  for d in codecs:
    try:
      r = "‡".encode(e)
      b = r.decode(d)
    except:
      continue
    if b != 'á':
      continue
    print(e, d)
```

El resultado fue un conjunto de 44 parejas de encodings, por ejemplo, una de ellas (que elegí por parecerme la más probable) era `cp1252 mac_roman`.

Esto significa que el usuario (siempre en hipótesis) recibió un archivo de texto que tenía la codificación `mac_roman` (utilizada en los **Mac** antiguos), pero la abrió con un editor que usaba la codificación `cp1252` (probablemente el bloc de notas de **Windows**), y por eso vio todos esos caracteres raros. Al copiarlos y pegarlos en Stack Overflow, se recibieron como Unicode ("utf-8"), complicando aún más el problema, pues no es posible entonces ver ya los bytes originales.

Así pues, codificando el texto dado por el usuario con `cp1252` y decodificándolo de nuevo con `mac_roman`, aparece ya legible:

```
texto_mal = "ƒsta ser‡ una historia de terror. Ser‡ una historia polic’aca, un relato de serie negra y de terror. Pero no lo parecer‡. No lo parecer‡ porque soy yo la que lo cuenta. Soy yo la que habla y por eso no lo parecer‡. Pero en el fondo es la historia de un crimen atroz. Yo soy la amiga de todos los mexicanos. Podr’a decir: soy la madre de la poes’a mexicana, pero mejor no lo digo. Yo conozco a todos los poetas y todos los poetas me conocen a m’. As’ que podr’a decirlo. Podr’a decir: soy la madre y corre un cŽfiro de la chingada desde hace siglos, pero mejor no lo digo. Podr’a decir, por ejemplo: yo conoc’ a Arturito Belano cuando Žl ten’a diecisiete a–os y era un ni–o t’mido que escrib’a obras de teatro y poes’a y no sab’a beber, pero ser’a de algœn modo una redundancia y a m’ me ense–aron (con un l‡tigo me ense–aron, con una vara de fierro) que las redundancias sobran y que s—lo debe bastar con el argumento. Lo que s’ puedo decir es mi nombre. Me llamo"
texto = texto_mal.encode("cp1252").decode("mac_roman")
print(texto)
```

> Ésta será una historia de terror. Será una historia policíaca, un relato de serie negra y de terror. Pero no lo parecerá. No lo parecerá porque soy yo la que lo cuenta. Soy yo la que habla y por eso no lo parecerá. Pero en el fondo es la historia de un crimen atroz. Yo soy la amiga de todos los mexicanos. Podría decir: soy la madre de la poesía mexicana, pero mejor no lo digo. Yo conozco a todos los poetas y todos los poetas me conocen a mí. Así que podría decirlo. Podría decir: soy la madre y corre un céfiro de la chingada desde hace siglos, pero mejor no lo digo. Podría decir, por ejemplo: yo conocí a Arturito Belano cuando él tenía diecisiete años y era un niño tímido que escribía obras de teatro y poesía y no sabía beber, pero sería de algún modo una redundancia y a mí me enseñaron (con un látigo me enseñaron, con una vara de fierro) que las redundancias sobran y que sólo debe bastar con el argumento. Lo que sí puedo decir es mi nombre. Me llamo

### Hashes md5

Ya sólo queda el ataque por fuerza bruta.

- Para generar todos los valores de `Y` posibles, uso `itertools.product` así: `product(string.uppercase_ascii, repeat=5)`. Cada uno de esos casos es una tupla de 5 letras mayúsculas, con las que formo la cadena `A-----O` (poniendo esa combinación en lugar de los guiones).
- Concateno al texto dado el valor de `Y`, separado por un espacio. Codifico la cadena resultante como `mac_roman` (ya que he deducido que ese era el formato original del archivo recibido por el usuario) y calculo el hash md5.
- Cuando el resultado me coincida con el hash esperado, imprimo el valor de `Y` y abandono el bucle.

Este es el código:

```
from hashlib import md5
from itertools import product
import string

esperado = "5580a2572d6e358ce8a493fd8739ff58"
for caso in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=5):
  Y = "A" + "".join(caso) + "O"
  intento = "{} {}".format(texto, Y)
  hash = md5(intento.encode("mac_roman")).hexdigest()
  if hash==esperado:
    print("{} --> {}".format(Y, hash))
    break
```

### Anticlímax

Al ejecutar el código anterior ¡no sale nada! Tras unos dos minutos de ejecución, se han agotado todas las combinaciones y ninguna ha producido el hash buscado. ¡Oooh!

Por tanto, o bien me he equivocado en la hipótesis sobre el *encoding* `cp1252`, o bien el texto del usuario estaba incompleto (esa frase final abruptamente cortada es sospechosa), o bien al pegar el texto desapareció un espacio, un retorno de carro... cualquier cambio mínimo haría que el hash fuese completamente diferente.

En definitiva, no he resuelto el rompecabezas, pero me he divertido por el camino y quería compartir mis pesquisas, por si alguien aprende algo de ellas.

## Caso reabierto y conclusión

El texto asignado a la variable `X` resulta ser el comienzo del relato [Amuleto](https://www.megustaleer.com/libros/amuleto/MES-082821/fragmento/).

A la vista de ese texto, está claro que la solución del enigma es `Y="AUXILIO"`, puesto que esa es la palabra que aparece en el texto original después de la frase `"Me llamo"` que había quedado incompleta.

Sin embargo:

```
 >>> md5("{} AUXILIO".format(texto).encode("mac_roman")).hexdigest()
 '2b27d348a6a9292ac6c8c10359dff1cc'
```

no es el hash dado en el problema. Lo que implica que el texto con el que estoy trabajando tampoco es el dado en el problema. Quizás faltan los retornos de carro (que el relato original sí tiene), quizás los retornos de carro están codificados como `\r` en lugar de `\n` (lo que sería consistente con el encoding `mac_roman`).

En fin, creo que ya he dedicado demasiado tiempo a esto :-)

Comment: Te voto positivo porque me ha gustado tu desarrollo, pero la verdad, tal como dices no creo que sea una respuesta adecuada ya que la pregunta no lo es.

Comment: Y por que no creas una nueva pregunta y la autorespondes? es una lástima, por que la pregunta (de paso en R) si no hay mucha voluntad de mejorarla por parte del OP va a terminar cerrada. Se agradece igual, por que no conocía esta novela de Bolaño.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Pero... ¿cuál sería la pregunta? XD

Comment: Y tienes varias cuestiones interesantes.. ¿Cómo puedo detectar el encoding de un texto? ¿Como obtener un hash por fuerza bruta?..