# Problema con el parámetro encoding de open Pyhton3

Tags: python, python-3.9

Estoy teniendo un problema al tratar de abrir el archivo rockyou.txt, los que conocen el archivo saben que tiene caracteres especiales, estoy intentando encontrar un encoding que no altere las palabras, ya probé con utf-8, ISO-8859-1, ASCII, pero todos terminan modificando el contenido, alguien sabe que encoding podría probar?, este es el código:

```
with open(wordlist, 'r', encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines_plane = []
        for i in lines:
                lines_plane.append(i.strip())
```

No es el código, me funciona muy bien, pero como les digo, modifica la palabra... palabras como estas son las que terminan modificadas: �xCvBnM, ie168, abygurl69, a6_123, *7¡Vamos!. Especialmente la ultima **"*7¡Vamos!"**.
Para que se den una idea de como es que lo modifica, les comparto el output:

```
['\x1axCvBnM,','\x08ie168','\x08abygurl69','\x08a6_123','\x04*\x037¡Vamos!\x03']
```

Para ser mas especifico quiero saber como mantener estos caracteres de manera normal. Un saludo.

Comment: podrías poner el texto original?

Comment: te refieres a abrir el archivo sin ningún encoding?

Comment: osea el texto norma, habre el archivo con block de notas y pon ese texto

Comment: te puede servir esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/162526/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-averiguar-el-encoding-de-este-texto)

Comment: Entiendo, ahora lo hare y les comparto...

Comment: xCvBnM,
ie168
abygurl69
a6_123
*7¡Vamos!

Comment: Le intento compartir como me sale pero la pagina lo codifica de manera automática, que puedo hacer??

Comment: mmm.. bueno, te comparti un enlace, tal vez te ayude

Comment: Claro!! ahora justo lo estoy leyendo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a dar una explicación según lo que sé.

Como bien se sabe el parámetro `encoding` de la función `open()` sirve para especificar la codificación del archivo, normalmente los archivos están codificados en *UTF-8*, pero esto varia según el *OS* (operative system), pues cada Sistema Operativo codifica los archivos de una forma u otra. La función `open()` utiliza por defecto la codificación de tu Sistema Operativo, esto es lo que retorna `locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True)` y lo puedes ver

```py
import locale
encoding = locale.getpreferredencoding(do_setlocale=True)

print(encoding)
#salida-> UTF-8
```

En mi caso es `UTF-8`, pero como dije esto puede variar, al no especificar una codificación Python utilizo la codificación de tu *SO* que pudo coincidir con el del archivo. Por otro lado como dices que importabas un modulo que trabajaba con bytes puede ser que el modulo haya *interferido* en la lectura del archivo, pues una solución era leer el archivo en modo binario `with open(wordlist, 'rb'):...`, pues al leer en modo binario pues esto retornan su contenido como objetos de bytes sin ninguna descodificación.

Answer (score 3):

Ya lo resolví gente, el problema era un modulo que estaba usando [pwn](https://docs.pwntools.com/en/stable/), yo lo usaba para simular barras de progreso y por algún motivo esto afectaba al código, el solo hecho de importarlo ya generaba el error de codificación, investigando mas sobre el funcionamiento de este modulo encontré que trabaja con bytes... por lo que supuse que seguro hubo algún tipo de conflicto al intentar decodificarlo a utf-8, si hay alguien que sabe porque sucede esto mas a profundidad que por favor me lo haga saber, saludos.

Comment: Que bueno, aunque hubiera estado mejor que supieras el por qué pasa eso

Comment: Claro, ahora estoy leyendo un poco para saber el porque, en cuanto lo sepa actualizare mi respuesta !!