# ¿Cómo resolver este rompecabezas criptográfico?

Tags: hash, md5

Estoy reformulando [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/162294/7123) de otro usuario, porque la original era irresoluble y posiblemente la pregunta será cerrada, pero creo que la técnica general para resolverla podría ser interesante.

Se trata en esencia de completar el texto siguiente, de modo que el hash MD5 del texto completo sea igual a uno dado. Este es el texto incompleto:

> "Ésta será una historia de terror. Será una historia policíaca, un relato de serie negra y de terror. Pero no lo parecerá. No lo parecerá porque soy yo la que lo cuenta. Soy yo la que habla y por eso no lo parecerá. Pero en el fondo es la historia de un crimen atroz. Yo soy la amiga de todos los mexicanos. Podría decir: soy la madre de la poesía mexicana, pero mejor no lo digo. Yo conozco a todos los poetas y todos los poetas me conocen a mí. Así que podría decirlo. Podría decir: soy la madre y corre un céfiro de la chingada desde hace siglos, pero mejor no lo digo. Podría decir, por ejemplo: yo conocí a Arturito Belano cuando él tenía diecisiete años y era un niño tímido que escribía obras de teatro y poesía y no sabía beber, pero sería de algún modo una redundancia y a mí me enseñaron (con un látigo me enseñaron, con una vara de fierro) que las redundancias sobran y que sólo debe bastar con el argumento. Lo que sí puedo decir es mi nombre. Me llamo ......."

Se nos dan los datos siguientes:

1. La palabra que falta al final (que he representado por `.......`) tiene 7 letras, todas ascii mayúsculas.
2. Esa palabra empieza por `A` y acaba por `O`.
3. El hash MD5 del texto final, codificado en en CP-1252 ha de ser `7292e0ae2227b2fd1cb089656aeff5e2`

¿Cuál es la palabra que falta?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Las funciones `hash` son irreversibles. Es decir, el hecho de que conozcamos el hash final (`7292e0ae2227b2fd1cb089656aeff5e2`) no nos permite conocer el texto de partida.

Los hashes criptográficos, además, cumplen otras propiedades que hacen imposible encontrar qué texto generaría un hash dado, sino es por **fuerza bruta**, es decir, probando todos los textos posibles y hallando el hash de cada uno, hasta encontrar uno cuyo hash coincida con el dado.

Por suerte en esta ocasión el *espacio de búsqueda* es relativamente pequeño. Con los datos que nos dan, sabemos que lo único que debemos probar son todas las combinaciones posibles de las 26 letras Ascii mayúsculas, tomadas de 5 en 5. Concatenando a cada una de estas combinaciones una `A` por delante y una `O` por detrás, tenemos las diferentes palabras que podrían completar el texto. Hay 26<sup>5</sup> casos, que aunque es un número grande (11881376) puede ser recorrido exhaustivamente en un par de minutos.

La siguiente solución usa Python para ir generando las combinaciones (`itertools.product` simplifica mucho el código) y calculando los hashses md5, hasta dar con el que produce el resultado deseado.

```
from hashlib import md5
from itertools import product
import string

texto = "Ésta será una historia de terror. Será una historia policíaca, un relato de serie negra y de terror. Pero no lo parecerá. No lo parecerá porque soy yo la que lo cuenta. Soy yo la que habla y por eso no lo parecerá. Pero en el fondo es la historia de un crimen atroz. Yo soy la amiga de todos los mexicanos. Podría decir: soy la madre de la poesía mexicana, pero mejor no lo digo. Yo conozco a todos los poetas y todos los poetas me conocen a mí. Así que podría decirlo. Podría decir: soy la madre y corre un céfiro de la chingada desde hace siglos, pero mejor no lo digo. Podría decir, por ejemplo: yo conocí a Arturito Belano cuando él tenía diecisiete años y era un niño tímido que escribía obras de teatro y poesía y no sabía beber, pero sería de algún modo una redundancia y a mí me enseñaron (con un látigo me enseñaron, con una vara de fierro) que las redundancias sobran y que sólo debe bastar con el argumento. Lo que sí puedo decir es mi nombre. Me llamo"
esperado = "7292e0ae2227b2fd1cb089656aeff5e2"
for caso in product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=5):
  palabra = "A" + "".join(caso) + "O"
  intento = "{} {}".format(texto, palabra)
  hash = md5(intento.encode("cp1252")).hexdigest()
  if hash==esperado:
    print("{} --> {}".format(palabra, hash))
    break
```

Tras 54 segundos aparece la respuesta en la pantalla:

```
AUXILIO --> 7292e0ae2227b2fd1cb089656aeff5e2
```

La palabra buscada era "AUXILIO". El tiempo de búsqueda podría haberse reducido usando multiprocesamiento, para comprobar varios casos en paralelo (tantos como *cores* tenga la máquina en que se ejecute, más de eso ya no representaría una ganancia de tiempo).

El texto, por cierto, era de [Roberto Bolaño](https://www.megustaleer.com/libros/amuleto/MES-082821/fragmento/)

Answer (score 1):

se me ocurren 3 formas:

1. fuerza bruta:
   considerando la entropía del dato faltante: 7 letras de un espacio de 33
   "ÁÉÍÓÚÑABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÜ"
   33^7
   = 42618442977 combinaciones

Considerando el contexto se puede reducir el espacio de letras a 26, 24 ó incluso 22, si lo que se busca por contexto es un nombre propio en mayúsculas, hay menos posibilidades de que se usen ciertas letras (X,Ñ,W,Q,Ü,Z), o la baja incidencia de letras repetidas, puede ser que se ignoren reglas de acentuación en mayúsculas (PERU/PERÚ, SANCHEZ/SÁNCHEZ).

Como el numero final de combinaciones está dentro de lo computable se puede usar el corpus completo y darle a la combinatoria.

**nota** se puede extender o reducir al considerar nombres con letras del alfabeto latino tipo: Walter, Ximena, Aarón, Zoilo, Güemes, Gonçalves. etc...

2. diccionario:

Por contexto se puede acotar el espacio de palabras a nombres propios en lengua castellana, mas comunes en México, en la última parte del siglo XX, etc...

3. google:

Se busca parte de la cadena conocida en google y si hay coincidencia se prueba